# Empty ion-router-outlet blocks the ion-content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I created a project with the side-menu template.
In the side-menu there are two sides (cities and weather).
The third page is displaying the weather for the selected city from the URL).
I have 3 routes:
`/cites` -> Cities.Page
`/weather` -> weather-overview.page
`/weather/:id` -> weather-detail.page

On both weather-pages, I want to show a tab-bar with all the selected cities.

This tab-bar is in an own component (city-tab.component):

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom"> 
    <ion-tab-button *ngFor="let city of cityList" [routerLink]="['/weather', city.ID]">
      <ion-label>{{city.Name}}</ion-label>
      <img src="https://www.countryflags.io/{{city.Country}}/shiny/16.png">
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

My problem is, if I want to show this component on the bottom, I can't click the content of the current page /weather and /weather/:id.
The chrome-inspector detects `<ion-router-outlet _ngcontent-eyp-c2 tabs="true" class="hydrated"></ion-router-outlet>`
which is blocking the hole ion-content.
Some lines above is a second `<ion-router-outlet main...`.
But the content is showing.

Here is the weather-overview.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Weather</ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-button (click)="handleclick()">Click</ion-button>
  <app-city-tabs></app-city-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

I also have 3 Modules:
- AppModule with routing to the other modules
- CityPageModule for the city.page
- WeatherModule for both weather-pages.

They will be loaded via lazy-loading.

I also tried to integrate the `<app-city-tabs>` in the app.component, but this was not helpful.

Thanks for your help, I appreciate.

app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Weather',
      url: '/weather',
      icon: 'sunny'
    },
    {
      title: 'Cities',
      url: '/cities',
      icon: 'business'
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu>
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

city-tabs.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CityLoaderService } from 'src/app/_sevices/city-loader.service';
import { City } from 'src/app/_models/city';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-city-tabs',
  templateUrl: './city-tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city-tabs.component.scss'],
})
export class CityTabsComponent implements OnInit {

  cityList: City[];

  constructor(private cityLoader: CityLoaderService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cityList = this.cityLoader.getCities();
  }

}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'weather', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'cities', loadChildren: './cities/cities.module#CitiesPageModule' },
  { path: 'weather', loadChildren: './weather/weather.module#WeatherPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Please can you add the code for the app.component.ts and app.component.html page. Thanks.

Comment: @LloydNicholson Both files are attached know.

Comment: I think the issue is with your routing module. Please share the app-routing.module.ts. The weather/:id route you've set up might be the problem.

Comment: @LloydNicholson I attached this two files above. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the `city-tab.component.html` here:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom"> 
    <ion-tab-button 
*ngFor="let city of cityList" 
[routerLink]="['/weather', city.ID]"> // <----- issue here 
      <ion-label>{{city.Name}}</ion-label>
      <img src="https://www.countryflags.io/{{city.Country}}/shiny/16.png">
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

The issue as shown in the code above is causing you problems. You are always directing your router to `/weather/:id` for both tabs you are clicking on. Change those to two separate tabs rather than using `*ngFor` to create the two tabs.

I don't have your `city-tab-component.ts` and `app-routing.module.ts` files available so I don't know how you have set up your routes but I'm assuming this might be the issue from what I can see.

Setup a child route within the city route like this:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
          {
            path: '', component: CityTabsComponent, children: [
              {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: './cities/cities.module#CitiesPageModule'},
              {path: ':id', loadChildren: './cities/cities-detail.module#CitiesDetailPageModule},

            ]
          },
        ];
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: If i change this to `[tab]="city.ID"` but if i opend one tab, I can't switch to another, because the path `/weather/cityid/cityid` is not used...

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'weather/2950159/264371'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'weather/2950159/264371'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
....

Comment: I've edited my answer according to what you wanted. I don't know what some of your other components are called like the dynamic id module so I made it up. Above I called it CitiesDetailPageModule.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I changed it a little bit, and it works.
I added your routes-block in the Weather.module (without lazy-loading) and removed `<app-city-tabs></app-city-tabs> ` from both pages. Now the content is clickable and the tabs are working correclty.